# FFMPEG Credits using png

Tags: ffmpeg

Can I add credits roll-up to a video using a png file and make it show at a certain time and last for 20 seconds? I have a 5:30-minute long video file, and I have a PNG file that's 7000 pixels high with transparent background, using ffmpeg, can I make the PNG file slide from bottom to top at a certain second and last for 20 seconds max while making sure it doesn't cover the video file and still have a transparent background? I tried creating a credits video and combining it with the original video, but I can't get the transparent background for some reason which is frustrating. This is the code I used to creat the credits video:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=0xff0000@0.0:s=1920x1080,format=rgba -loop 1 -t 0.5 -i "rollup_test.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0xff0000:0.2:0.0,scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.05/TB),fps=30[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.05':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -y credits.mp4
```

Comment: Hello, what does "can't get the transparent background" mean exactly? What's the output? Always describe what's happening rather than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want it to start scrolling at a stated time?.. Do you want it to scroll for 20 secs, or stop and display for 20 secs? Either way, what is expected to happen after the 20 secs. Also, if you want 7000 pixels to scroll in 20 seconds, that's 350 per second.... That's a lot!